# Fully charged battery voltage of devices

Tags: power-supply, batteries, lithium-ion

What is the voltage value of fully charged (and what is the value of fully discharged, out of curiosity) battery (1s li-ion) in common devices such as smartphone? Of course li ion provide ability to being charged up to 4.2/4.25V, but staying at this level for longer period (at least couple of hours (?)) degrades significantly battery life.

Edit - basing on: https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries

About the discharge cycles:
[image]

About the storing:
[image]

Comment: Depends on the battery. Many lithium ions will be about 4.2V fully charged. Never seen much issue with keeping them at 4.2V for days, let alone hours.

Comment: There is no single voltage used by all devices for all li-ion batteries.

Comment: Some devices (e.g. iPhones and MacBooks) will now try to avoid charging the battery to full capacity for prolonged periods. When charging, they will stop at about 80% (of capacity, not sure how that translates into voltage), and only charge to 100% when they think you’ll need it (based on usage patterns) or when you tell them. Manufacturers learn about batteries all the time and try to adapt to maintain better battery health.

Answer (score 5):

Fully depends on designer's choice.

This will vary wildly with device models and various li-ion chemistries. Designers will always tailor the cutoff voltage to what is needed for the product:  Performance or longevity? Also, there seem to be many different "li-ion" chemistries to choose from. [image]

For example, have you noticed there used to be two types of cells (3.6V vs 3.7V nominal) for old Nokia phones?

For some anecdotal evidence.
My old phone (K750i) used to terminate charge at 4.15V (it used li-pol cell, though). After 8 years, the old cell had comparable capacity as a newly purchased cell (which might have been in storage for all that time?) The daily use had almost no effect on it. In comparison, my laptop (Acer T3810) was keeping cells at 4.3V when 100%, restarting charge at 95% (Not sure, but I think 4.25V). The battery was dead within 4 years of nonstop use, with only about 50 cycles used. The frequent charging killed it.

Update: Out of curiosity, I measured other devices. Current phone (android) charged to only 80% leaves the cell at 4.10V. Makita charger terminates a 18V Li-ion battery charge at 20.59V (4.12V per cell).

Table taken from [here](http://www.tili-energies.com/en/nd.jsp?id=17)